# Exceptions & Errors in Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

This is a general question. In Crystal, what is the difference between an `Exception` and an `Error`?

For example, in the `JSON` package, there is both [`JSON::Error`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.24.1/JSON/Error.html) and a [`JSON::ParseException`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.24.1/JSON/ParseException.html), which inherits from `JSON::Error`. Also, how do we know if a method might raise an `Exception` (or `Error`, I really don't know the difference)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference between `Error` and `Exception`, it's just inconsistent naming.

That should probably be standardized some day. IIRC the consensus was mostly to use `Exception` only for the general base class and use `Error` for all implementations for specific errors. In that scheme, `JSON::ParseException` should actually be `JSON::ParseError`.

Method descriptions should typically state which errors can be thrown, but this might not be a conclusive list (if at all). There is no way to semantically deduce *all* exception types that can be thrown by a specific method.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think a proposal to standardize naming/standardize listing errors/exceptions in docs would be good?